# Obtain last active time of window from ID

Tags: gnome, xorg, xdotool, wmctrl

Distribution used (if that helps): `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Gnome 3.18.5`

I am trying to automate raising a specific application window using a keyboard shortcut. My requirements:

- Use keyboard shortcut to *raise window of specific application type*.
- Ensure that the windows chosen *are from the current workspace*.
- Ensure that the window raised was the one that was *most recently active when considering just that application*.

> For e.g.: Consider two gnome-terminal windows open alongside other
>   applications in the same workspace. My script should automatically
>   focus on the last accessed gnome-terminal window.

I have tried using `wmctrl -xl` to get the list of windows and filtered them by class as well as workspace. However, **I cannot find a way to get the last active timestamp using the window IDs**.

```
$ wmctrl -xl | grep -i "$(wmctrl -d | grep '*' | cut -d ' ' -f1) gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal"
0x02247629  1 gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal  <hostname> Terminal
0x0224784b  1 gnome-terminal-server.Gnome-terminal  <hostname> Terminal
```

Is there anyway to get this metadata from the window ID? Any help is appreciated.